Data Factory Pipeline - how to handle the data type System.Array for Avro format
I have an ADF pipeline that copies data from blob storage to data lake Gen2. There are multiple avro files, of which my copy data activity merges, into one file, for a given date period.
I am encountering an issue with one particular column 'media_urls' due to the file format being System.Array.
Note that this pipeline handles multiple different avro files and subfolders, so it does not have explicit mapping for the copy data activity.
Is there a workaround for this error, without mapping the data?
Error message;
ErrorCode=DataTypeNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column: media_urls,Location: Source,Format: Avro,The data type 'System.Array' is currently not supported by Avro format.,Source=,'


